# Mount pegboard to wall

Tags: mounting, studs, aluminum

I am attempting to mount a pegboard(the type you climbed up in gym class  http://www.roguefitness.com/rogue-pine-maple-peg-board) to a drywall covered wall. Originally I thought lag bolts into the studs of the wall would work but then found out the studs in the wall are aluminum. After that I considered using toggle bolts and tried to get one into the stud but that seemed to be impossible. I have no idea what to try next to get the board mounted to the wall safely. It weighs about 40lbs and will have around 200lb people climbing it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Track down the load ratings for the aluminum studs in question.  If they can take the kind of weight you plan (remember to double the effective weight due to climbing forces), then you'll want to open up the wall and bolt the pegboard to as many studs as possible.

Comment: The safest way may be to support the peg board with several 2x4's  that are anchored to the metal studs. the 2x4's going from floor to ceiling. the 2x4 will handle the weight and the height will allow for several anchors up high to help with the lateral forces.

Comment: How do you recommend anchoring 2x4s to the metal studs?